# A set of views in iOS development that act like a collection view?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a view containing 3 items. They are in a 2 column format so if all 3 items were visible you would have 2 on the top row and 1 on its own in the second row. This is fine but these items are going to be dynamically turned on or off in code.

How can I lay them out so that they flow correctly. i.e. the 3rd item moves onto the first row if the second item is turned off. Can it be achieved through auto layout constraints? I also need the outer view to collapse in height if one or all of the items are hidden. Can this be achieved in the interface builder of xcode or does it have to be done in code?

**Diagram** below of the variations that could happen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use something like this for your collection view
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: You should only use PSTCollectionView if you need to support iOS 6 or earlier. It doesn't solve this problem in a way that UICollectionView doesn't.

Comment: so by using PSTCollectionview when you remove the middle item...you simply call collection view reload....it should move to the first row